# How to use Intel Pin Tool on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I have installed the intel pin tool 20.04 and I want to make an inscount.test. I have run the command `make inscount.0` successfully.
However, when I go to the `obj-intel64` directory and use the command `pin -t inscount0.so -- /bin/ls`, it says there is no such command.
I have also tried
`./pin.sh`
`./pin`

Comment: when I want to use the `pin` command, it says there is no `pin` command. Basically, it is a syntax problem. which format should I use when I want to run the command? `pin`, `./pin` or`./pin.sh`?

Comment: Thhis [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202773/using-intels-pin-tool-on-ubuntu) answers my question.